# How to get all available values for FilePathField in Django 1.5?

Tags: python, django

I have a model, which has `FilePathField` attribute. It has a folder to search, regular expression to match and other needed parameters.

I need a standard method to get the list of all available for this `FilePathField` paths. Or it does not exist?

Comment: What is this `FileFieldPath`? Some non-standard field type?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. FilePathField :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't one. You can write your own using `path`, `match` and `recursive`. However, this is how the admin widget form for `FilePathField` gets all the paths - https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py#L999

```
from django.forms.fields import FilePathField
a = FilePathField(path='/path')
print a.choices
```